# XFA pdf from xfa:datasets/xfa:data is missing

Tags: java, pdf, itext, xfa

I am trying to fill up an XFA form with the help of itext. Up until now, I used to be able to read the xfa:data section of an empty form and also the dd:description element and using the dd:description to understand the structure of the XML, dynamically create the XML and thus populate the form.

But my logic in the code, worked on the assumption that the xfa:data will always be present albeit empty elements in the empty form. Recently, the pdf has been changed, such that the xfa:data section is created only after any element in the form has been filled and saved.

I think there is some javascript in play in Adobe Live Cycle designer in order for this to happen. I don't have access to Adobe Live Cycle Designer nor can I modify the structure of the form.

I was wondering, can I somehow trigger the creation of the xfa:data section exactly as if I filled up something in the form, using itext? Then the remainder of my code will work as is.

I can't use the dd:description to create the entire XML because, the form has a few hidden elements in the XML which are defaulted to some values. I need those values populated and that's why I say can I trigger the creation of xfa:data just like someone filled a value in the form.

Comment: *an I somehow trigger the creation of the xfa:data section exactly as if I filled up something in the form, using itext* - iText has no JavaScript processor; you *think there is some javascript in play*. Thus, no. Instead you may try to understand that JavaScript and emulate its behaviors.

Comment: *iText has no JavaScript processor* is true if you talk about iText core. It's not true if you talk about XFA Worker. It's not clear from the question whether iText core is used, or XFA Worker. (Note: XFA Worker *flattens* the form and therefor needs to execute JavaScript, e.g. to format or calculate values of certain fields.)